# How to remove unused CSS/JS and Improve server response time for WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress, web-performance, web-vitals

I've optimized my WordPress site performance and also checked its performance using [web.dev](https://web.dev/measure/)

**But still, have the following issues that I couldn't solve:**

1. Remove unused CSS
2. Remove unused JS
3. Initial server response time was short

How can I Solve this issues?

Answer (score 0):

Performance optimisation is a huge theme and probably can't be covered simply in one answer, but I still can point you to the right direction.

**Remove unused CSS & JS**

First, you have to determine what CSS and JS files you really load on each page, find out where they come from and think about whether you really need them or not. It often happens that a lot of heavy CSS & JS files are being loaded only for the sake of a simple animation that is used once somewhere on website. You can see all the files loaded in browser console, or with the help of services like [GT Metrix](https://gtmetrix.com/). If you find assets that you don't need but they're still being loaded, first try to find a source (for example: a theme or a plugin) that loads them. Popular themes and plugins have settings for disabling some parts of assets so it's an easy one. For those that don't have any settings you can try this piece of code, just replace file names with yours.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'remove_styles' );
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'remove_scripts' );

// Remove styles from plugins we don't need
function remove_styles() {
    if ( $GLOBALS['pagenow'] != 'wp-login.php' && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_dequeue_style( 'coblocks-frontend' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'coblocks-frontend-css' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'wp-editor-font' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'duplicate-post' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'thickbox' );
    }
}

// Remove scripts from plugins we don't use and don't need
function remove_scripts() {

    // just in case we use those in wp-admin, exclude only from front-end loading
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'coblocks-animation' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'coblocks-animation' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'thickbox' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'thickbox' );
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    }
}
```

Ideally you need to keep your CSS and JS as small as possible but it can be tricky in modern WP themes that use a lot of it.

**Initial server response time**

Long response time mean that your server takes too long to return any data. 99% of the times it is either because of badly-optimised website or a weak server. Latter can be easily solved by moving to another hosting provider or changing hosting plan.

Website optimisations are trickier and may require profiling, especially if you already have proper full page caching installed . Generally, I can describe all the general cases like this:

1. Slow server response + no caching = try caching first. WP Super Cache, WP Rocket or similar plugins.
2. Slow server response + caching = try hosting providers with nginx-caching support (basically serving static content on each page load). I can recommend Kinsta or Pressjitsu.
3. Slow server response + a lot of dynamic content = You can't cache things the same way as regular websites. Here you need an experienced dev who should first profile you website with tools like xhprof or blackfire.io and then gradually work on optimising performance of the worst performing functions.